# Disable scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, layout, scrollbar

If you go to http://google.com, you will notice that there is a disabled scrollbar.

On my site, to avoid annoying the user with page shifting, I want a scrollbar on every page. But, if the page truly does not need to scroll have the scrollbar disabled.

This seems like a trivial task, but I can't seem to find the solution. Perhaps I'm just missing something.

Anyway, can anyone help with this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Mmh normally you should not have to specify anything for this. It should work this way out of the box...

Comment: For me (at least with Chrome), out-of-the-box did not display any scrollbar - disabled or enabled. I always wanted to show a scrollbar no matter what.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood the question.... nevermind :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`overflow: auto` makes the scrollbar appear when needed and disappear when not. For the scrollbar to always appear, use "scroll"

```
body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Yep, that did it. I knew it would be trivial.

Comment: This is a CSS3 property, so not all browsers (guess) support it yet.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to disable the scrollbar with javascript, but you can set the css `overflow` property to `auto` so that when there is overflow, the scrollbar is available, and when there is no overflow, the scrollbar is disabled. Applying this to the body will most likely be the best solution:

```
body {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Good answer, and it helped me in my own project. `auto` is a great one!

Answer (score 3):

the scroll bar is there but disabled depending on what browser you're using. I'm using FireFox on the Mac and there is no scroll bar on the example you provided.

Unfortunately this is one of the annoyances I've come to deal with when developing websites.  I'm pretty sure that `<body style="overflow:hidden;">` (as others have answered) does not solve the problem.  If the page needs a scrollbar, it will add it, but if it doesn't, the browser you use will determine whether or not to show a disabled scroll bar or no scroll bar at all.  I haven't found a solution to this problem.

#### Correction

After reviewing [@Stephen P's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17300/stephen-p) answer, I think he's on to something. I haven't tested it, but it makes sense.

Comment: +1 because it's a good answer and I don't know what the downvote was about.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(" $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');");
```

Comment: Do you mean _just_ `$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');`?

Comment: you should be include the javascript to this code its working $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');